# Binding WPF controls with XML

Tags: c#, xml, binding, button

What I need to do is like when user click on "English" from the combobox, the text of the button1 will be in English, likewise if the user click on "Japanese" from the combobox, the text of the button1 will be in Japanese.

So i have created a XML file, and imported it to the WPF.

And I have binded the Content of the button1 to be Content="{Binding langCollection[0].button1, Mode=Default}". So by default, when the user click on "English", the button1 text will be in English.

But now, I want it to be like when user click on "Japanese", the text of button1 will be in Japanese.

So what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

try to use Linq to XML (XDocument, etc.) and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2343164/492638) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599249/492638)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into the MVVM pattern.  Your button's text should be bound to a property in your View Model which will change depending on the language selected.