# C# - Combobox index change after editing

Tags: c#, combobox, indexing, editing, textchanged

A moment ago someone answered my question on how to edit the combobox loaded with a text file, and how to save the recently edited line.

[C#: Real-time combobox updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750990/c-real-time-combobox-updating)

The problem now is that I can only change one letter before it updates, and then the selectedindex changes to -1, so I have to select the line I was editing again in the dropdown list.

Hopefully someone knows why it's changing index, and how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: We can't see the prev answer here or how you implemented that. Please update the previous question. Voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Real-time combobox updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750990/c-real-time-combobox-updating)

Comment: may be it's changing index because it checks if items[selectedIndex] equal comboBox1.Text and returns -1 if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private int currentIndex;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += RememberSelectedIndex;
    comboBox1.KeyDown += UpdateList;
}

private void RememberSelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void UpdateList(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && currentIndex >= 0)
    {
        comboBox1.Items[currentIndex] = comboBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the other code might have worked too, but this one seemed a little more flexible to me.

Answer (score 4):

As my understanding of the problem goes, you can do one thing. In the comboBox1_TextChanged method, instead of putting the previous code, you can just set a bool variable, say textChangedFlag to true and you can set the default value of this variable as false.
And then use KeyDown event to edit the combobox item.
I will give a sample code.

**Sample Code:**

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textChangedFlag )
            {
                if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex>=0)
                {
                    int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
                    comboBox1.Items[index] = comboBox1.Text;
                    textChangedFlag = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

You can put this code in KeyDown event handler method.
Hope it helps

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedIndex equals -1

Comment: Thank you for the code, I cant test it untill tomorrow so I'll let you know.