# Simple WPF + MVVM binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a class named `MyWindow` the derives from `Window`. I use the MVVM pattern so in code-behind I have the following field:

```
public MyViewModel ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
```

`ViewModel` contains a collection of `Person`, and all I'd like to do is to bind a `ComboBox` to this collection, show `Person.Name` as the header for each `Person`.
I would also like to have another field in `ViewModel` that will be data-bound to the selected item.

Please help me.

Comment: Have a look at his link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list/561427#561427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well firstly you have to set the datacontext of your window to the viewmdodel in the constructor if you have not already done so:

```
this.DataContext = MyModelView;
```

Then you can set the ComboBox as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Persons} SelectedItem={Binding CurrentPerson,Mode=TwoWay} DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Where Persons is the Collection of Persons and Current Person is the Property the selected person will be bound to.

Answer (score 2):

1. Assign the modelView to the MyWindow.DataContext property.  This makes it available for data binding.
2. Define the data binding in the combobox xaml like this:

`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
           SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson}" > 
</ComboBox>`

This assumes that your modelView has a property PersonCollection which is a collection of Person objects, a property Name on the Person object, and a property SelectedPerson on the modelView of type Person.