# Swapping images based on variable

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, streaming

I have an application that is using XAML and C# (MVVM) to create a interface that allows you to start and stop a camera feed.

What I would like to do is to switch between a OFF and ON image depending on the variable `IsOn`.

I know how to set the image in the UI Manually,

```
<Image Source="/MyApp.WpfUI;component/Resources/Images/Webcasting.png" />
```

but I am not sure how to best change the image dynamically based on conditions. I have considered IF statements, but am not sure how to go about that.

Does anyone have any advice or ideas?

Comment: I am, I am using vs2010 pro,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One answer would be:**
Binding the IsEnabled attribute of your control that displays the stream to a property in your code that returns a boolean.
**In your View:**

```
<Image IsEnabled={Binding IsOn} Source="/MyApp.WpfUI;component/Resources/Images/Webcasting.png" />
```

In this property's *getter*, put your conditional statements to determine whether or not to return a true or false.
**In your ViewModel:**

```
public bool IsOn 
{
    get
    {
        if(<some condition>)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- Don't forget to use your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged to alert the UI when necessary.
- If you implement a setter, you could have a button on the View that would toggle the value giving you manual control.
- Binding can be used to alter the **Source** of the stream as well using the same technique as above.  I.e., the getter would return the path to the video stream or the path to a static image that says "Video Off".  **However, this is dependent on whether or not the control you're using can handle that.** Instead of the *IsEnabled* attribute, you would use binding with the *Source* attribute.
- Here a couple links that will show you some similar implementations of this:

  - [High Overview of WPF (MVVM) w/Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)
  - [Simple Binding Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053940/simple-wpf-mvvm-binding)

Good luck.

Comment: I do like this idea, but being very new at XAML I am not sure how to implement this. Could you provide an example of what the XML element would look like?

Comment: There is a XAML example in my answer above - first code snippet.

Comment: `<Image Source="/MemorialStreams.WpfUI;component/Resources/Images/Webcasting.png" DataContext="{Binding}" />`
is what I currently have, but it is bound to nothing. I do see the options for static and relative sources - but I fear I might be going in the wrong direction

Comment: You should be setting the DataContext to a ViewModel in the code-behind of your View.  Once you've done that, see my code example above (I have modified it).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. You can either perform this manually using an if statement as you mentioned in your question, or you can create a `DataTrigger` & assign it to your control's `ControlTemplate`.

DataTriggers allow you to set property values when the value of a particular data object matches certain conditions you specify in the XAML. I'd recomend reading the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on DataTriggers for some basic examples of how these work.

Comment: I am looking into it now. Thank you!