# WPF Combobox binding with List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two properties, one which is a list of string and the other just a string.

```
private List<String> _property;
public List<String> Property
get
{
return new List<string>(){"string1", "string2"};
}
set{_property = value
}

public String SimpleStringProperty{get;set;}
```

I also have a Combobox defined in XAML as such

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Property , Mode="TwoWay"}" Text="Select Option" />
```

Now the combobox correctly displays two options :"string1" and "string2"

When the user selects one or the other, I want to set `SimpleStringProperty` with that value. However, the 'value' im getting back from the combobox through the two way binding is not the selectedItem, but the `List<String>`. How can I do this right? I'm fairly new to wpf, so please excuse the amateurism.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Property}" SelectedItem="{Binding SimpleStringProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Select Option" />
```

That's untested, but it should at least be pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to the String property using the `SelectedItem` property of the `combobox`.

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Property}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SimpleStringProperty}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          Text="Select Option" />
```

Answer (score 2):

What helped me:

1. Using  **SelectedItem**
2. Adding **UpdateSourceTrigger**=*PropertyChanged*
3. **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem**="*True*" to be sure Selected item always synchronized with actual value
4. **Mode**=*TwoWay* if you need to update as from source as from GUI

So at the end best way, if source is

```
List<string>
```

**Example:**

```
 <ComboBox 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SomeBindingPropertyList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SomeBindingPropertySelectedCurrently, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**Additional Info**

- *Difference between SelectedValue and SelectedItem*:

  1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/2758833
  2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883923/2758833
- *SelectedValuePath* Documentation:

  1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath
- *SelectedValue updates possible bugs for .NET 4 and .NET 4.5:*

  1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/247482/2758833

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation on ComboBox.SelectedValue instead of just guessing about it.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was referring to. Some people try to use `SelectedValue` without setting `SelectedValuePath`. The question you linked to is *an example* of somebody trying to use `SelectedValue` without setting `SelectedValuePath`. The accepted answer to that question totally failed to understand *why* `SelectedValue` wasn't working. People don't read the documentation. I recommend that you read the documentation, rather than posting wrong information on StackOverflow.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx). HTH.

Comment: This worked for me, i was missing: UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged