# How can I bind the content of the combobox in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, binding

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,175" DataContext="{Binding }" />
```

I've set the `DataContext` of the xaml to a class.

Within in this I have a class called `Player`. A Player has a property array of another object called `Quests`. Each `Quest` has a `name` property.

How can I bind the content of the combobox to the `Quest` array, and have each item represented by its `name` property?

I'm assuming I will have to use binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ComboBox binding ItemsSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373643/wpf-combobox-binding-itemssource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the statement `DataContext="{Binding }"` simply takes the current value of the `DataContext` property and assigns it back- this will have no effect.
2. Assuming that the `DataContext` of this view has a property named `Quests`, what you need to do is:

   ```
   <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,175" ItemsSource="{Binding Quests}" />
   ```

Note that `ComboBox` derives from `ItemsControl`, and as such- setting the `ItemsSource` property will always do the trick.

You will probably need to create a data template for the quest item in order to see something of actual interest. [This should get you started with Data Templates.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx)

Once you've created a Data Template, set it to the ComboBox using the `ItemTemplate` property (Once more, a courtesy of `ItemsControl`).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found out :D

If anyone else had the same problem:

Assume you have a List called Foos in your window / page. Foo has a property Name. Now you set up the binding in XAML as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}"
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
SelectedValuePath="Name"
```

Referenced from [WPF Databinding combobox to a list<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854308/wpf-databinding-combobox-to-a-liststring)