# Binding List<string> to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

I want my combobox item names and values to be taken from my List
of course I don't want my view model to hold combobox items list.

I got a list `a,b,c,d`

i want my combobox to have items

my viewmodel got

```
public List<string> PropsList { get; set; }
```

my view got

```
<ComboBox Name="cbPropName" ItemsSource="PropsList"/>
```

it gives me
combo with P r o p s L i s t

:(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nahum you'll have to use `ItemsSource="{Binding PropsList}"`, assuming PropsList is a Dependancy property in your code behind or, even better, a property in your data context that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In your case you'd have to set the `DataContext` property of your View to be the `ViewModel`

Comment: It happens for me all the time, even after writing so many XAML lines :-). If it was helpful you could V my answer...

Comment: sure =D theres jsut that 10 minute wait thingy. people in this ite are just too fast.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 <ComboBox Name="cbPropName" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PropsList}" />
```

also check this out: [Binding WPF ComboBox to a Custom List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)