# How to bind class member in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections

I want to bind a class member of an element I added to a collection to `DisplayMemberPath`. I bound a `ObservableCollection` to `ComboBox.ItemSource` and want to show the property `name` in the combobox's list which is a member of my class `AxisBase`.
Here is my code:

```
private ObservableCollection<AxisBase> axis { get; set; }
```

`axis` I use to hold elements of the following class

```
class AxisBase
{
    ...
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This is how my xaml looks like

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox_AchsenListe" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=axis, Path=AxisBase.name}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_MainWindow, Path=axis}"</ComboBox>
```

Does anyone know how to bind `name` to `DisplayMemberPath`?

Comment: look at my answer update. I give you an example.

Comment: Thanks alot. I had to change my ObservableCollection to `public` which finally made it work. Just little little things mess the whole code :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change DisplayMemberPath value

```
 DisplayMemberPath="name" 
 SelectedValuePath="name"
```

and look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)

I have created sample application for you 
here the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AxisBases}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
            SelectedValuePath="Name" 
        Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,134,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

here is code behind

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboBoxSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AxisBases = new ObservableCollection<AxisBase>
                        {
                            new AxisBase {Name = "Firts"},
                            new AxisBase {Name = "Second"},
                            new AxisBase {Name = "Third"}
                        };
        //Set the data context for use binding
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AxisBase> AxisBases { get; set; }
}

public class AxisBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

It works OK and binding also in combo box appears 3 items.

Comment: @theknut: [The manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), have you read it?

Comment: I tried but I even fail at setting the metadata. It can never load my class and the designer crashes.