# Best practice for selecting a type from UI

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

First, I am new to WPF and MVVM. I have an Interface like this

```
Interface IItemType
{
  bool save()
}
```

and I have three concrete classes which they are inherited from this Interface

```
Public Class Type1:IItemType
{
   public bool save()
   {
     //save something with method 1
   }
}

Public Class Type2:IItemType
{
   public bool save()
   {
     //save something with method 2
   }
}
```

I have three RadioButtons (they can extend in future to 4,5 or more) in my View which I want to choose the Save Method (Class `Type1` or `Type2`) by selecting one of these RadioButtons. 
The question is how can I bind these Radios to my ViewModel to not violating the pattern designs like OCP and etc (as In future I want to add more types and Radios)?

Meet the MVVM best practice design?

** EDIT **

Imagine I have the following Property

```
Public IItemType CurrentType { get; set; }
```

I want to put the Class `Type1` into CurrentType property when the first Radio is selected
and put the Class `Type2` into CurrentType property when the second Radio is selected and so on.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you make use of RelayCommand pattern

Read about full pattern detail : [**WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
     //code realted Icommand interface
    }

```
RelayCommand _saveCommand;
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveCommand == null)
        {
            _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Save(),
                param => this.CanSave );
        }
        return _saveCommand;
    }
}
```

Bind command like

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}">
```

Comment: At first the user selects a Radiobutton then he/she click on a button for example to do what he/she wants. Can I use RelayCommand for that?? Shall I Put this in my concrete classes?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - its better to read the article in detail once that you get idea about this and modify the code accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a single item from a list, a ComboBox is a nice choice.  Here's some info about databinding with the ComboBox in WPF.  [Binding WPF ComboBox to a Custom List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)