# Binding a combobox selected item content to an element

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

I am working with WPF using Entity Framework and Data Binding for managing PRODUCT and BRAND in a database. PRODUCT includes a BrandID property. In order to display in a datagrid a brand name instead of an ID, I used a DataGridComboBoxColumn like this:

C#

```
gridProducts.DataContext = this.DbContext.Products;
brandColumn.ItemsSource = this.DbContext.Brands;
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="gridProducts" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          RowEditEnding="dg_RowEditEnding" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="BRAND" x:Name="brandColumn" DisplayMemberPath="BrandName" 
       SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=BrandID}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```

It works fine. But now I need to bind the combobox selected value into a textbox text. I tried this:

XAML

```
    <TextBox Name="brand" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, 
      ElementName=brandColumn}"/>
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea of how can I bind the combobox selected value (the BrandName - not the BrandID) in the textbox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding it in xaml, create a common property in entity/viewmodel and bind it to that.