# DataBinding of a ComboBox after InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have two `ComboBox` on my code:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxSelectCamera" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCameras}" SelectionChanged="comboBoxSelectCamera_SelectionChanged" />
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxCities" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCities}" />
```

On my `Window` I have this code so the `ComboBox` understand where the `Path` comes from:

```
<Window ....
     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
     .... >
```

Both combos are binded to two listes that I created on my `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeCitiesCombo();

    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize the control that checks for cameras
    InitializeCameraControl();
    FillCameraProperties();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

The first `ComboBox` list is created **before** the `InitializeComponent`, so when its combo is created, it fills with the specific content.

The second `ComboBox` list is created **after** the `InitializeComponent`, because it depend on an object that loads the cameras, and, I don't know if that's the reason, but if the list is created **after** `InitializeComponent`, it doesn't fill the `ComboBox`.

I know there are other ways to fill a list of connected cameras on my computer, but **I have** to use that control that is created on the `InitializeComponent` and initiated on the `InitializeCameraControl()`.

Any idea on how can I fill this `ComboBox` after the `InitializeComponent`?

**EDIT:** Declaration of both Lists:

```
private List<CameraInfo> ListCameras { get; set; } 
private List<String> ListCities { get; set; }
```

Somewhere in code, the `ListCites`:

```
ListCities = new List<String> { Madrid, Barcelona, Alicante, Valencia }
```

Somewhere in code, my control returns a list of the connected cameras (it works, it has elements but they don't display on the combo):

```
ListCameras = MyUserControl.ConnectedCameras;  // this returns a valid list of `CameraInfo`
```

My `CameraInfo` class:

```
public class CameraInfo
{
    public CameraInfo(string name, string id);

    public static implicit operator string(CameraInfo cameraInfo);

    public string Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

Note that while we discuss this, I tried to change on the combo of cameras the `DisplayMemberPath`.

**Binding error:**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Template' (type 'ControlTemplate')
```

Comment: What class are you using for your cameras list? Is it just List<CameraClass> or ObservableCollection<CameraClass>?

Comment: Show us the declaration of the both lists. They aren't `ObservableCollections`, right?

Comment: What kind of list should they be? Note that the one that is created before the `InitializeComponent` is filling right, but the other one, not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there is your major problem. First, change your lists like this.

```
private ObservableCollection<CameraInfo> _listCamera; 
public ObservableCollection<CameraInfo> ListCameras
{
    get { return _listCamera ?? (_listCamera = new ObservableCollection<CameraInfo>()); }
}
```

I'm only showing it for one list, but you have to do it for both. To fill the list, don't reinstantiate them, but clear them. E.g.

```
private void FillCameraInfo()
{
    IEnumerable<CameraInfo> example = new[] { new CameraInfo(), new CameraInfo() };
    ListCameras.Clear();
    foreach(var exampleEntry in example)
        ListCameras.Add(exampleEntry);
}
```

It's only an example, so I kept it as simple as possible. If you would reinstantiate them the bindings would be 'destroyed'.

That the first `ComboBox` is filled correctly lies in the fact that you're filling it, before you initialize the components with their bindings. So the items can be found. The second `ComboBox` is not aware of the changes in `ListCities`, because it's not notified by it. If you use `ObservableCollection<T>` the `ComboBox` will be notified, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information. And the binding should work as expected.

**Edit - Why you shouldn't reinstantiate the collections**

If you would do the following to put the data into the collection

```
public FillCameraInfo()
{
    ListCameras = new ObservableCollection<CameraInfo>(someData); 
}
```

the bindings would still listen to the 'old' instance. But you changed the reference of `ListCameras` and nobody listens to the new instance.

**Edit - Why you don't see anything**

Ok, this is a bit odd, but it's like it is. The order of declartion of a `ComboBox` binding is pretty important, so that it works properly. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list) for the right order.

Comment: It still doesn't fill anything...
:(((

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean when you say `if you would reinstantiate them, the bindings would be destroyed`??

Comment: @Sonhja Oo - This is just an example. You can use what ever you want. I only wanted to demonstrate how you should fill the data in the collection. Nothing more...

Comment: Ok, do you get any binding errors? Is anything appearing in the `ComboBoxes`? Did you look with the debugger, what does the collections contain?

Comment: No binding errores, nothing appearing on `ComboBoxes`, the collection has the proper data, and I never reinstantiate it...

Comment: Oo - Are you a developer? *Doesn't work...* is not a proper error description. What's the **Debug Output** window of VS saying? Any binding errors?

Comment: Get calmed... of course I'm a developer, but I can't explain much more if my order is the correct... Sorry.

Comment: I'm calm. But you must admit *doesn't work* is not very helpful. ;o) Ok, then please show me your current state and don't touch anything meanwhile I've a look. ;o) Btw, I think the binding error comes from elsewhere. You should delete the line `DataContext = this` in your c_tor. From what I'm seeing, it could cause this issue, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Sure it's not so helpful... Ok, I erased the `DataContext = this` but I still have null  `ComboBox`.  But I still have a `BindingExpression path error...` (see last edit). Actually the same one.

Comment: Ok, solved! I introduced the `DisplayMemberValue` after erasing what you said last, and now it works. Thanks a lot, your answer was really helpful and instructive :o)

Comment: Puh...finally. xoD You're welcome. I already began to question me and my knowledge. One last tip. Get familiar with MVVM it's the best pattern to implement WPF/SL applications.

Comment: Hehe yes, finally! Thanks, I have some tutorials of MVVM, but I still didn't decide to start with. But I surely will do soon :o)