# how to bind a ComboBox to a list of string

Tags: c#

how to bind a ComboBox to a list of string 
here is my list :

```
  public ObservableCollection<string> m_Category = 
                                              new ObservableCollection<string>();

 <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding m_Category, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex ="0"  
        SelectionChanged ="MyComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

## Edit

Plz note that my comboBox is inside a DataTemplate
Thks

Comment: What's the `DataContext` of your `ComboBox`? your `m_Category` should be a Property of that `DataContext`.

Comment: how to define a datacontext

Comment: what's the difference between DataContext and itemsource

Comment: `DataContext` can be passed down from parent to children in the visual tree, so you can set the `Window.DataContext`, your comboBox will have the same `DataContext` unless you explicitly assign a new one for it. `DataContext` is used to **implicitly** set the `Source` for all the bindings, that's why your `Binding` doesn't have any `Source` set, it just need to specify other info such as `Path`, ... `ItemsSource` is just some access point for you to put data into your comboBox to display the data. I thought you already know what DataContext is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use binding here in your ItemsSource because  you don't have a datacontext set  here 
just in code behind do this (after m_Category filling )

```
MyComboBox.ItemsSource =  m_Category ;
```

Otherwise you should create a class contains a property  like this and your bind will work

```
 public class MyDataContext
        {
    ObservableCollection<string> m_Category = 
                                              new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public  ObservableCollection<string>   M_Category 
    { get;set}
      }
```

//Change your bind  like this

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding M_Category, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex ="0"  
        SelectionChanged ="MyComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

in your main window you  can do something like this

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         MyDataContext myDataContext =  new  MyDataContext(); 
           //for example here  
            For(i=0;i<100;i++)
                    myDataContext.M_category.Add(yourItem)
        this.DataContext =  myDataContext ; 
    }
```

Comment: i did like you mentioned but it didn't work; about M_Category  where to fill it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you set a DataContext to your ComboBox otherwise the binding won't work.

Your XAML file should look something like this:

```
 <ComboBox Name="cbPropName" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=m_Category}" />
```

it should work, if you still have a problem take a look in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)

Comment: So how can i add a dataContext to the combobox

Comment: Its quite basic question, if you aren't familiar with DataContext and how it's works, I'm suggesting you to read the next article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF