# Display Combobox Items as a property of object from list of objects, working with wpf datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview

I have a class in Model.cs and list of the objects of this class is created in viewmodel.cs. 
I using the list of these objects as an`Itemsource` to the Data Gridview. Each of the object in the list has `Name` as a property and I want list of these names in the each of the comboxes in the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. I tried quite a few things and I'm unable to get the desired result. I'm using Prism for this application

I have the following code in ViewModel.cs

```
    private IList<BeamData> _allBeams

    public IList<BeamData> AllBeams
    {
        get { return _allBeams; }
        set { _allBeams = value; }
    }


    public LoadInfoViewModel()
    {
         _allBeams = new List<BeamData>()
        {
            new BeamData(){Name ="B1"},
            new BeamData(){Name ="B2"},
            new BeamData(){Name ="B3"}
        };
    }
}
```

The beam data class looks like this :

```
    public BeamData()
    {

    }
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
```

My XAML files has this code

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Table" ItemsSource="{Binding AllBeams, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AllBeams}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name">
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Fyi, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377143/how-to-bind-a-combobox-to-a-list-of-string) does not answer my question.

**Desired output :** 
If you look at the code above, `B1, B2, B3` are Name (property) of the object BeamData, each combo boxes in the column should have all the names Viz, `B1 , B2, B3`

Comment: <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AllBeams}" should be <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding}"   only

Comment: This does not solve the problem, moreover I would like to understand what does it change?

Comment: In your code the itemsource for combobox is expecting AllBeams property from DataGrid ItemSource AllBeams.

Comment: Can you please send a screen shot of the desired output

Comment: thanks for the query :) I have edited the description.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ItemsSource` in the `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Table" ItemsSource="{Binding AllBeams, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Name">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllBeams, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllBeams, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

A `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not a visual element that inherits the `DataContext` so you can't directly bind its `ItemsSource` property to a property of the view model.

Comment: This throws and error : 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is something else in your code that throws this exception.