# WPF Combobox get selected item text and associate an internal value (not displayed) to each item of the combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, .net-3.5

I have below WPF combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
            Grid.Column="1"
            SelectionChanged="MyComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbiEmployeeManagerType">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Resources/Manager.png" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="AliceBlue"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">Manager</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbiEmployeeEngineerType">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Resources/Engineer.png" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="AliceBlue"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">Engineer</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**First problem**:

Within `MyComboBox_SelectionChanged` I know how to detect which item is currently selected in the combobox through `MyComboBox.SelectedIndex` but I do not know how to get the text that appears displayed and currently selected in the combobox. For example, If I select the second item in my combobox, I want to obtain "Engineer". How can I do it?

**Second problem**:

Also I would like to do the same as in combobox winforms in which you can display a member (`DisplayMember` property of combobox in winforms) and internally to associate it a member value (`ValueMember` property of combobox in winforms) which you can read when you selected the item within the combobox. For example suppose the following combox items with their associated values.

- "Manager"  : 1000A
- "Engineer" : 1000B

So "Manager" and "Engineer" would be displayed in the combox and when I would select "Manager" I would obtain its associated value, that is, 1000A, the same for Engineer. Is it possible in WPF? If so how? I have read that it is possible using `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` combobox properties but I do not know how to do it. Do I need to create a class and populate the combo from there and then using binding? Any piece of code will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
For second problem finally I have done similar to what is explained [here](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-displaymemberpath-in-listbox/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562145/add-combobox-items-from-code-behind-wpf).

Comment: Two notes. 1. It doesn't seem to make any sense to have a VirtualizingStackPanel in a ComboBox. Remove the entire ComboBox.ItemsPanel. 2. You repeatedly add ComboBoxItems with a StackPanel with two child elements. That should be done by a DataTemplate in the ItemTemplate property of the ComboBox. Inside the DataTemplate you would bind to properties of the item type. The ItemsSource property of the ComboBox would be bound to a collection of this item type. See [Data Templating Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) for how to start.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you can access to TextBlock of ComboBoxItem by digging through the `SelectionChangedEventArgs e` of the `SelectionChanged` event with this kind of line of code:

```
private void MyComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem;
    var itemStackPanel = selectedItem.Contents as StackPanel;

    // Get the TextBlock object from 'itemStackPanel' object
    // TextBlock is with index 1 because it is defined second
    //  after Image inside the StackPanel in your XAML
    var textBlock = itemStackPanel.Children[1] as TextBlock;
    // This variable will hold 'Engineer' or 'Manager'
    var selectedText = textBlock.Text;

}
```

or you can use this short line that combines all the above code in one line:
(the `?.` is C# 6 feature to check for null in case something goes wrong)

```
var selectedText = (((e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem)?.Content as StackPanel)?.Children[1] as TextBlock)?.Text;
```