# Binding Combobox to custom list windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a custom list with structure
category
   -id
   -name
   -color
I create a list and bind it to combobox name categoryListBox in my xaml page.

I have tried using this piece of code

```
List<category> categoryCollection = await       categoryList.GetCategoryListAsync();
categoryListBox.ItemsSource = categoryCollection;
categoryListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
categoryListBox.SelectedValuePath = "id";
```

using [this as resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)

Whenever I run the app, all I get is a blank screen, although when I get collection of items using

```
 var item = categoryListBox.Items;
```

it shows it of type System.Generic.Lists having the number of items it should have. I seem to be on a standstill here, and don't know whats wrong with it. I even looked at an [example](http://www.skimedic.com/blog/post/2008/10/02/The-WPF-ComboBox-SelectedItem-SelectedValue-and-SelectedValuePath-with-NHibernate.aspx), but couldn't understand much.

This is the definition of combobox

```
 <ComboBox 
     Canvas.ZIndex="100"
     Name="categoryListBox"
     Foreground="Black"
     Margin="10,0"
     PlaceholderText="Select.."  
     Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}"/>
```

[And here is the file for category class.](http://pastebin.com/V8Gmq09N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values in `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties must be a **property** name (not variable), and **accessible** (`public` modifier).

so if you edit your `category` class, by replacing this:

```
int id;
string name;
int color;
```

with:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int color { get; set; }
```

It should work.

Comment: without the `public` qualifier, shouldn't this work with just the `{get; set;}` since C# defaults to `internal` and that should still be accessible?

Comment: no. must be **public**. probably because the logic of control 
Is an external assembly.