# LINQ query results into List

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a class called `Name` with one property.

```
public class Name
{
    public string comboName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm attempting to run a LINQ query to return all `FullName`, and then create an instance of the `Name` class for each, assigning `FullName` to the property `comboName`. The instances are added to a `List`, and then I want `List` values to be added to `ComboBox1` drop down values. Below is the code I've written so far.

```
void ComboBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GiftIdeasDataContext dc = new GiftIdeasDataContext();

    var qry = from r in dc.Recipients
                select new Name()
                {
                    comboName = r.FullName
                };

    List<Name> lst = qry.ToList();
    ComboBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
}
```

**Issue:** When the code is executed the `ComboBox1` drop down only shows the string 'myMemory.Name' 9 times (the number of names which are in the `Recipient` table). Should I just create a list and assign string values to the list instead of using a class?

I've only been using the console window with c# up to now, this is my first project using WPF, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list  ..Also have a look at  DisplayMemberPath,                SelectedValuePath for combobox

Comment: When you debug, what do you see in `lst` if you put a breakpoint on the line `ComboBox1.ItemSource = lst;`

Comment: The list contains 9 values which are 'myMemory.Name'.. if I click the index drop down it shows `comboName` and then the actual value which I would expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ComboBox` needs to know how you want instances of your `Name` class displayed. As you didn't explicitly tell it, it uses `Name.ToString()` to display your `Name` instances.

You can explicitly tell the `ComboBox` how to display instances of your `Name` class through setting `ComboBox1.DisplayMemberPath` to `comboName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Name> lst= from r in dc.Recipients
                select new Name()
                {
                  comboName = r.FullName
                }.ToList<Name>();
```

or you can convert like the following :

```
List<Name> lst = (List<Name>)qry.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = dc.Recipients.Select(r => new Name{ comboName = r.FullName }).ToList();
```

Comment: it always help to have some explanation to the solution