# How can I fill a combo box with the names of columns from a database?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm brand new to WPF.  I have a combo box that I want to fill with the names of the columns of a database.  I have seen from other posts that

> select *
>
> from MyDatabaseName.information_schema.columns
>
> order by table_name, ordinal_position

will give you the names of the table, but how do I then add each element to the combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox`. Of course, how you are going to set is your choice. Some are more recommended than others. However, one simple choice is to directly set it in code.

Assuming that `cb` is the name of your ComboBox and `yourlist` is the name of your list, use ``cb.ItemsSource = yourlist;

There are other choices such as Binding the ItemsSource too. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list) or Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ItemsSource of your ComboBox

And Set DisplayMemberpath in XAML

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName"/>
```