# WPF ComboBox Selected Item with reference to an object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to define a selected item in a combobox. It working fine if I'm just using a String to declare the selected item but not if using an object.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Woche" Margin="10" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding weekSelection}" 
  DisplayMemberPath="name" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding nodeWeek, Mode=TwoWay}"  
SelectedValue="name" />
```

-

```
private week _nodeWeek;
public week nodeWeek
{
    get
    {
       return _nodeWeek;
    }
    set
    {
        _nodeWeek = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("nodeWeek");
    }
}
```

-

```
 public class week
 {
    public int val { get; set; }

    public String name { get; set; }
 }
```

-
setting the selected item

```
this.nodeWeek = new week() { val = times.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now), name = "KW " + times.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now).ToString() };
```

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Could you try to bind with datasource property ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected item must be always one of the list of your items source. You cannot create new objects and assign them to the `SelectedItem`. The Combobox simply compares object references not the content.

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the reference based on the ObservableCollection?
I need to select an item of the Collection by "val" oder "name"

Comment: That is the easy part. Just `Find` the entry: nodeWeek = weekSelection.Find(x => x.name == TheNameYouWantToFind);

Comment: Just for example. If I'm trying to set the reference like this: nodeWeek = weekSelection[1]; it's still not working, there must be something else wrong I guess

Comment: Hm, in my test scenario it does work. Is the `DataContext` set correctly?