# Why does my ListBox List bind correctly with ObservableCollection<string> but not ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox   
    ItemsSource="{Binding SupplyGroups}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ModelSupplyGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

`SupplyGroups` is an `ObservableCollection<SupplyGroup>`

`SupplyGroup` is an object with an `int SupplyGroupId` and a `string SupplyGroupTitle`. There is a `public override string ToString()` so the ListBox gets the Title for display.

`ModelSupplyGroup` is a Property that accesses the Model's SupplyGroup.

When the window loads up, the value saved as `ModelSupplyGroup` does not cause the matching ListBox row to be selected.
If I modify the code so `SupplyGroup` object is replaced with a `string`, it works correctly.
The binding appears to work in the opposite direction, so if a ListBox row is selected, it will update the bound `ModelSupplyGroup` correctly.
Inspecting the Objects in the matching SupplyGroup in the ObervableCollection and ModelSupplyGroup, they have identical values for ID and Title.

```
public SupplyGroup ModelSupplyGroup
{
    get
    {
        return this.purchasingRepository.GetSupplyGroupById(this.Model.SupplyGroupId);
    }
    set
    {
        this.Model.SupplyGroup = value;
    }
}
```

The `GetSupplyGroupById()` returns the full object from the Id.

Comment: You do not need to (and usually will not) override the ToString method. Instead, just set the ListBox's DisplayMemberPath property to select a SupplyGroup that is to be shown by the ListBox. If the visual appearacne is more than just showing a single property value, declare an appropriate DataTemplate as the ListBox's ItemTemplate. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for details.

Comment: In order to select an item by its ID, set `SelectedValuePath="ID"` and bind `SelectedValue="{Binding SupplyGroupId}"` or whatever is an appropriate vuiew model property. Also note that the SelectedIndex, SelectedItem and SelectedValue properties bind TwoWay by default. You do not need to set Mode=TwoWay explicitly.

Comment: Your actual problem might be that the GetSupplyGroupById method does not return a SupplyGroup instance that is contained in the SupplyGroups collection (but rather a new one). Better use the SelectedValue/Path approach in that case

Comment: In addition to @Clemens comments, did you read the "related" SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-a-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The view model property to which the `SelectedItem` property of a ListBox is bound must return an object that compares equal to an element of the collection to which the `ItemsSource` property is bound.

If the item class does not override the `Equals()` method, equality means referential equality, which means that the view model property must return an object reference that is contained in the source collection.

The method

```
purchasingRepository.GetSupplyGroupById(this.Model.SupplyGroupId);
```

created an object with matching properties, but a different instance, i.e. one that was not contained in the SupplyGroups collection.

Modifying the property fixed the problem:

```
get
{
    foreach (var item in SupplyGroups)
    {
        if (item.SupplyGroupId == this.Model.SupplyGroupId)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This could also be written using LINQ like

```
get
{
    return SupplyGroups.FirstOrDefault(
        sg => sg.SupplyGroupId == Model.SupplyGroupId);
}
```